# How can I get TypeScript to error if a property of a function is accessed through bracket notation?

Tags: typescript, eslint

```js
const foo = () => 1;

// doesn't throw a type error since functions are objects.
foo['bar'];
foo[11];
```

Is there a way to get TypeScript to throw an error here instead of allowing this?

Comment: Enable `noInplicitAny`. But that will bring out a lot of other errors too.

Comment: Yes, enable `--noImplicitAny` (and `--strict` in general).  It will expose a lot of errors, the vast majority of which will be ones you should fix and not suppress.  Good luck!